# Change the folder name of URL with a text link?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp-classic

I have a site with two languages contents, both have the same file names but are stored in different folders: /EN/ and /ZH/.

I would like to have a text link which allow it to be clicked and change the folder name of the URL.

like by clicking the text link "ZH", it will change the URL as:

from => "http://example.com/GroupA/EN/index.asp"

to   => /ZH/index.asp"

I have search around and found a script as below:

Script:

```
$(function() {
    $(".flag").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var to = $(this).attr("href").substring(1); //removes the hash value # (#en will become 'en')
        var from = jQuery.url.segment(-2);
        var url = from.replace('/' + from + '/', '/' + to + '/');
        document.location = url;
    });
});
```

Body:

```
<a id="flags" href="#en" class="flag">English</a>
```

However, when I tried the script above, it only add "#en" to the end of my URL, like
http://example.com/GroupA/EN/index.asp#en

Comment: Are you sure the jQuery library is included in your page?  The script is not being run and the link is behaving as if it were clicked as normal with no scripting applied.  Check your browser's console for errors and let us know if there are any.  If you don't know how to view the console, let me know which browser you use.

Comment: I am using IE8, thanks.

Comment: With IE you need the developer's toolkit which you can get from MS for free.  Press F12 and see if a new window opens - the console is in there.  It's always good to be able to see any errors JS produces.

Comment: Just tried to press F12, and a new window pops up.  No error is shown.

Comment: Also, I tried to amend the href="#en" to href="../ZH/" and the URL change from "http://www.abc.com/GroupA/EN/index.asp#en" to "http://www.abc.com/GroupA/ZH/" ; Does it mean anything? It looks much closer to what I want if the current pathname can be added to the end of it.

Answer (score 1):

```
$(function() {
    $(".flag").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var to = $(this).attr("href").substring(1); //removes the hash value # (#en will become 'en')
        var url = window.location.hostname  + "/GroupA/"+to.toUpperCase()+"/index.asp"
        window.location.assign(url);
    });
});
```

Comment: Do I use this to call the script as well? <a id="flags" href="#en" class="flag">English</a> ;  It comes out the same, only add #en at the end of the current URL.